# border вокруг QWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcreator, qss

У меня есть QWidget с несколькими элементами и мне надо вокруг него сделать серую рамку ( можно через qss ), но я прочитал что QWidget нет border-radius.
Как можно обернуть в рамку QWidget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй QFrame если нужна поддержка border-radius.
Например:

```
setStyleSheet("QFrame#myWidget {border 1px solid; border-radius: 2px}")
```